# Can someone demonstrate the Principle of Superposition with a First Order Differential Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I understand that it applies to second order and any other differential equation as long as they are Homogenous and Linear, but I can't seem to see how it works with a First Order Differential Equation.

Does this mean that I can take 2 General Solutions of a 1st order differential equation, take them in a linear combination and set that as my solution?

Comment: Yes what you said is true. Observe that differential operation is a linear operator.

Comment: It indeeds mean that . It's just a trivial verification. It can be rephrased as ‘The set of solutions of a linear homogeneous differential equation is a vector space. Furthermore, if the equation is of order $n$, this vector space has dimension $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

$$\frac{d}{dx} f(x)=f(x)$$
has a solution $f(x)=\exp(x)$.

$g(x)=2 f(x)+3 f(x)=5 f(x)$ is also a solution.

Comment: Is f(x) a general solution or a unique solution? If it's general, what about the constants? What happens to them once taken in a linear combination?

Comment: The *general solution* to his DE is $c\exp(x)$, where $c$ is any constant. The concept of *uniqueness* of solutions to DEs arises in the context of *initial value problems* (IVPs). For example, if we moreover require that $f(0)=1$ in the above DE, then we can observe that $\exp(x)$ satisfies both the DE and the *initial value* $f(0)=1$. Now, a further question is "is $\exp(x)$ the only function that satisfies the IVP?", to which the answer is "yes". The *principle of superposition* basically says that if $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are solutions to a DE, then so is $f_1(x)+f_2(x)$.

Answer (score -1):

Variation of $C$ i.e the constant, can give you several solutions of the form $y(x)=x+C.$

$y$ can take on any solution like $y(x)=x,\, x+1,\, x+2,\, x+3$ etc, and so since all of those are solutions, then another solution can be the sum of those equations.

To my thinking it's $C$ which brings in the principle of superposition, implying that $y(x)=$ Summation of $x+c$ from $c=0$ to $n$.